# SSRS Expression to Populate Dynamic Parameter Drop down Based on Year and Financial Year (CRM)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

how to dynamic current year to  Previous 5 year display year in filter(Drop Down)

how to dynamic Financial Year to Previous 5 Financial year display year in filter(Drop Down)

Please find attachment screensort.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IT47.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have a table with date that you can use you could do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
select YEAR(getdate()) as [TimePeriod]
UNION SELECT YEAR(getdate()) -1
UNION SELECT YEAR(getdate()) -2
UNION SELECT YEAR(getdate()) -3
UNION SELECT YEAR(getdate()) -4
) t
ORDER By TimePeriod DESC
```